# Can't make rounded corners

Tags: electron-react-boilerplate

I'm using Electron React Boilerplate and i'm trying to make beautiful rounded corners but instead i'm getting white square corners. Do someone know any solution?

[This is what my app corners looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmqsF.png)

This is my BrowserWindow code:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  show: false,
  width: 396,
  height: 520,
  transparent: true,
  frame: false,
  resizable: false,
  webPreferences: {...preferences}
});
```

Edit: Here is more code

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './Home.css';
import Titlebar from './FirstOpenScreen/Titlebar';

export default function Home(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <div className={styles.home}>
      <Titlebar />
      <h1 className={styles.h1}>Hello, world.</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And my CSS:

```
div.home {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #252525;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I have never worked with electron but understanding that it uses javascript HTML and CSS, there is a CSS property called `border-radius` for rounding corners.

Comment: Hello, I have already tried to use `border-radius` on my JSX element but this didn't worked. The white squared borders on the image was my attempt to use `border-radius`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is helpful for us to see as much code as possible in order to best help. Are you able to provide a snippet of the full code, or the CSS you are using?

Comment: Of course! I edited the post with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help. I was analyzing my own code and tried a CSS property that I saw on the internet, and it ended up helping me.

The solution is simply to add `overflow: hidden` to the CSS file to work.

```
body {
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```